# How to assign an IPv4 domain name to an IPv6 server behind NAT (local network)?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, ipv6, vlan, web-hosting

I have a server behind a router that has an IPv6 address.  I configured my DNS to AAAA record, but looks like the domain can only be accessed by IPv6 computers.  Is there any way to port a domain name to an IPv6 network, so that anyone on IPv4 accesses a domain name will be forwarded to my IPv6 server?

I used to do this with tunneling where they assign you a subdomain, but now they closed down, and I wonder if I can assign myself a subdomain.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Tunneling and domain names really have nothing to do with each other, so I don't understand what sort of setup it is you are describing. Maybe all you need is a port forwarding of port 80 and 443 from your router to the server. Maybe you are looking for a service like http://v4-frontend.netiter.com/ which I operate.

Answer (score 0):

The reason only IPv6 clients can access your site is that the `AAAA` record resolves to an IPv6 address (from your router, I assume).

To make your server accessible over ipv4 you have to set up an `A` record with the public IPv4 address of your router. If it doesn't have one, you'll have to find a way to tunnel a publicly-accessible IPv4 address to your router's IPv6 address.

You should provide more details like a network diagram, the domain and addresses involved.

Comment: Well, freenet6 shut down, and my server (which sits on a private lan) lost it's tunnel.  So I set up a tunnel through HE (which is 6in4), but unfortunately I cant tunnel behind the router to local network in 6in4, so i set a 6in4 tunnel to my router, and my server got an IPv6 via prefix.
I was wondering, now that my server has an IPv6 ip (behind a router), can I somehow tunnel an IPv4 domain name to it?  Godaddy won't do it :(  Thanks!

Comment: Please explain in detail which hosts and network segments have which IP protocol version.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to direct taffic to a domain that currently has an A record (IPv4), you need to add an AAAA record with the IPv6 address. Barring firewalls, IPv6 traffic will be routed to you.

HE offers DNS services that will handle both forward (AAAA or A) records and IPv6 reverse (PTR) records.  Your IPv4 address provider likely has control of the PTR record for your IPv4 address, although they can delegate it to you.